# How to let floated divs stretch outer div's width

Tags: css, html, css-float, stretch

I'm building a new page where I want to include a slider that slides from left to right. I have a div within a section and within that div I have three floated articles. What I want is that the (wrapper) div element stretches with it's width so that the inner articles get in one horizontal line.

Here is some code: http://jsfiddle.net/jFSz4/

I can't get it to work without specifying a fixed width to the div element (like 3000px) but that's not what I want. Imagine what would happen if I added a fourth div.

So, I want each article to be exactly 800px width and the wrapping element needs to adjust to that width.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a solution using `position:relative` for the wrapper and `position:absolute` for the articles where each article's `left` offset is increased by `800px` (the width of one article)

I'm using pseudo-class `:nth-child(n)` to set this, but you could just as easily set each article's class/id instead

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/jFSz4/20/

---

**edit: solution without `position:absolute`**

here's a solution using `display:inline-block;` [(which is arguably better than `float`)](http://www.google.com/search?q=inline-block+vs+float)

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/jFSz4/22/

```
#slider{
    background: green;
}

#slider div{
    background: yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#slider article{
    display:inline-block;
    width:800px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: It is a nice option but of cource i'd rather use float on the articles because that saves me from editting the left property everytime I want to add a margin or such (or add a fourth elements for example). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sweet! That seems to work nicely. Only thing is that the wrapper is not stretching (which can be seen if you add a background color to it).

Comment: the `div` wrapper? I guess I'm not seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, the wrapper div element that is stiens the articles.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

http://jsfiddle.net/jFSz4/19/

Adjust `margin-left` on the `.articles` element to slide the articles. This is the property you would animate with JavaScript.

*NOTE: I'm using 400px on articles simply for easier testing.*

---

**CSS:**

```
    #slider{
        background: green;
        width: 800px;
    }

    #slider .container{
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #slider .articles{
        width: 20000em;
    }

    #slider article{        
        background: yellow;
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
    }
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<section id="slider" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="articles" style="margin-left: -200px">
             <article>
                 <header>
                     <h2>1</h2>
               </header>
             </article>   

             <article>
                 <header>
                     <h2>2</h2>
               </header>
             </article>   

             <article>
                 <header>
                     <h2>3</h2>
               </header>
             </article>  
        </div> <!-- /articles -->
    </div> <!-- /container -->
</section>
```

Comment: But I do not want to specify a specific width to the articles container div (like your 20000em). It just need to be as width as the width of the three inner articles (3x 800 and some margins).

Comment: You have to **A.** specify a really wide width and hide the overflow as in my example, **or B.** use tables.  Otherwise, your floats will just stack after their combined widths is >100% of the container width. All you have to do in my example is change '400px' to '800px' and you should be good to go.

Comment: The thing is, i wanted to use the wrapper element's position to do some tricks with js, but it that element does not fit nicely around the inner elements, it cannot be done. But I think I have no option here but to specify a width to the wrapper element.

Comment: What were you planning on doing? There may still be ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: To start, I want the wrapper element slide from left to right (moving the inner articles also from left to right). That works nice but I want to block the left or right movement if the right position of the wrapper will go below zero for example. Since we now have a fixed with, that position is no longer reliable.

Comment: As I said in the answer, you can easily slide the wrapper from left to right (moving the inner articles) by animating `div.articles` `margin-left` property. e.g. to slide to the 3rd panel, animate it to -1600px. Also, preventing sliding to a panel that doesn't exist should be done using a panel index, e.g. `if (go_to_index < 0 || go_to_index > num_panels) return false;`

Comment: Well, the preventing of the sliding is an issue I would solve later. For now I just want, let say, a slide left movement where at first the third panel is not visible (because it falls behind the overflow) and slides in on the first slide left movement.

Comment: I'll go with the fixed width of the wrapper and fix the disabling of the slide options some other way. Thanks alot!

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are asking? http://jsfiddle.net/jFSz4/3/?
I simply added `width:100%` to the #slider div element

Comment: I don't think that's it...I still don't see the three articles in one line. Do you?

Comment: I don't see it working in any of the browsers...I see a horizontal scrollbar appearing though.

Answer (score -1):

Use percentages...http://jsfiddle.net/jFSz4/2/

and display:inline with your float...

Comment: But I want the articles to be exactly 800px in width.Now it seems to adjust to the 100% of the outer div (which is basically just the width of the window). In your fiddle I still see them below each other by the way.

Comment: To clarify...you want EACH article to be 800px in width OR the summed total and however many article to be 800? And, all articles inline?

Comment: Each article has to be 800px exactly...and the wrapping element needs to adjust to that width.

Answer (score -1):

So this seems to work in both IE and FF, but I'm not quite sure that it's what you want...
I've switched article tags to div with article class and added `width: 100%;` to slider div.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
 <title>x</title>
 <style>

    html, body{
    width: 100%;
    }
    #slider{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: green;
    }

    #slider div{
        position: absolute;
        background: yellow;
        overflow: auto;       
        width: 100%;
    }

     #slider .article{        
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<div id="slider" >
    <div>
         <div class='article'>
             <header>
                 <h2>1</h2>
           </header>
         </div>   

         <div class='article'>
             <header>
                 <h2>2</h2>
           </header>
         </div>   

         <div class='article'>
             <header>
                 <h2>3</h2>
           </header>
         </div>  

    </div>  
 </div>   

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I saved it locally and changed the width of the article (or div's in your example) to 800px and boom, right back to where we started.